# msvc precompiled header warning suppress

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-warnings, precompiled-headers

In my C++ project, I use precompiled headers as a compile time optimization. However, when I enable /Wall option in the compiler settings, I am not able to suppress any of warnings in the precompiled header file.

**Header File:**

```
#ifndef _PRECOMPILED_H
#define _PRECOMPILED_H

#pragma warning(push, 0)
#pragma warning(disable: 4514)
#include <vector>
#pragma warning(pop)
#endif /* _PRECOMPILED_H */
```

**Source File:**

```
#include "precompiled.h"
```

I end up with tons of warnings in vector.

When I do the same, but in a regular file, everything works as expected.
Any solutions for this problem?

**I am using Visual Studio 2013 community edition update 4.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `/Wall` with Visual C++. It doesn't mean the same as `-Wall` with g++. Use `/W4` (rough equivalence with g++ `-Wall`).

Answer (score 0):

I did not get a 4514 warning from including vector. 
You have only disabled 4514, and only in the vector header. I think this is happening in other code that happens to use vector, and the warning message (which you did not post) refers to the vector header since that's where the function being removed by the optimizer was declared.